# AngularJs auto-complete Search bar with Dropdown list having Images with Text

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, angular-strap

I need to implement a drop-down with options having both images and respective text, where a user can type the search query and with each key strokes the drop down list updates. I used [Angular-Strap typeheads](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/typeahead#typeaheads) to achieve this functionality.

This is my angularjs snippets -

```
$scope.productsDisplayed = $scope.allProducts.map(function(product, index) {
  return {
    value: product.Name,
    Name: product.Name,
    Brand: product.Brand,
    Image: product.Image,
    _id: product._id,
    label: "<img src = '" + product.Image + "'> " + product.Name
  }
});
```

This is my html snippet -

```
<input ng-model="selectedProduct" bs-options="product as product.label for product in productsDisplayed" placeholder="Enter Product Name" bs-typeahead type="text">
```

The search is working and I'm able to search relative products with each key strokes.

**Problem**

I'm getting the link of the images in the drop down list instead of the images themselves - 
Ex - Dropdown entires look like this =>

```
<img src = '/test/image/upload/v0000000000/products/abcdefghi.jpg'> " + Deodrant
```

**Query**

How i can get the actual images of the products with their names in the drop down list?

Kindly don't suggest [angucomplete-alt](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt) as I've tried using it & found that libraries much slower compared to angular-strap typeheads. Also, I've got images on those links, so links are not faulty.

Comment: Please refer this, seems like same, you will get better idea : https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: @JigarPrajapati Thanks but your link goes no where relevant to this post. It opens to "Hello Plunker".

Comment: Sorry to say, actually wrong link was pasted , please refer this right one : https://plnkr.co/edit/1EgIUSbg5qzZgsMEDptu?p=preview

Comment: @JigarPrajapati Thanks, but I don't see how it solves my issue of having images in the drop-down. I kindly ask to you to go through the question details once more.

Answer (score 1):

Use `bs-options="image.value as image.label for image in images"`

JS

```
  $scope.urls = { "Gear": 'https://dummyimage.com/100/000/f00.jpg&text=GEA',
                  "Globe": 'https://dummyimage.com/100/000/0f0.jpg&text=GLO',
                  "Heart": 'https://dummyimage.com/100/000/00f.jpg&text=HEA',
                  "Camera": 'https://dummyimage.com/100/000/fof.jpg&text=CAM'
  };

  $scope.selectedImage;
  $scope.images = [
    {value: 'Gear', label: '<img src="'+$scope.urls.Gear+'"> Gear'
    },
    {value: 'Globe', label: '<img src="'+$scope.urls.Globe+'"> Globe'
    },
    {value: 'Heart', label: '<img src="'+$scope.urls.Heart+'"> Heart'
    },
    {value: 'Camera', label: '<img src="'+$scope.urls.Camera+'"> Camera'
    }
  ];
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" 
       class="form-control"
       ng-model="selectedImage" 
       data-min-length="0" data-html="1" 
       data-auto-select="true" data-animation="am-flip-x" 
       bs-options="image.value as image.label for image in images" 
       placeholder="Enter image name" bs-typeahead>
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/qAH4tlkTUFKMKakFIPkj?p=preview)